# How to make combination, if any one of the element exists that can be added to make sum?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-itertools

To find all possible combinations that can be added to make given sum.
Combinations can be formed with `multiple elements` and also `if any single element exists.`

**Input:**

```
l1 = [9,1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5] 
target = 8

**Constraints**
1<=(len(l1))<=500000
1<=each_list_element<=1000
```

**Output:**

```
Format : {index:element}
{1:1, 5:1, 4:6}   #Indices : 1,5,4   Elements : 1,1,6
{1:1, 2:2,  6:5}
{5:1, 2:2,  6:5}
{1:1,  3:7}
{5:1,  3:7}
{2:2,  4:6}
```

**More Scenarios:**

```
Input = [4,6,8,5,3]
target = 3
Output {4:3}

Input = [4,6,8,3,5,3]
target = 3
Output {5:3,3:3}

Input = [1,2,3,15]
target = 15
Output {3:15}
```

**Below code covers for all above scenarios.**

**Scenarios to be handled, along with above.**

```
Input =[1,6,7,1,3] 
target=5
Output={0:1,3:1,4:3} , {0:1,0:1,4:3}, {3:1,3:1,4:3}

Input=[9,6,8,1,7] 
target=5 
Output={3:1,3:1,3:1,3:1,3:1}
```

As suggested by `@Chris Doyle` in previous question, will be using that code.
([How to find indices and combinations that adds upto given sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348264/how-to-find-indices-and-combinations-that-adds-upto-given-sum))

**Code:**

```
from itertools import combinations


def find_sum_with_index(l1, target):
    index_vals = [iv for iv in enumerate(l1) if iv[1] < target]
    for r in range(1, len(index_vals) + 1):
        for perm in combinations(index_vals, r):
            if sum([p[1] for p in perm]) == target:
                yield perm


l1 = [9, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5]
target = 8
for match in find_sum_with_index(l1, target):
    print(dict(match))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension

```
from itertools import combinations
l1 = [9,1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5] 
target = 8

for i in range(len(l1)):
  for c in combinations(l1,i):
      if sum(c) == target:
        res = { i:x for i,x in enumerate(c)}
        print(res)
```